# In Development environment database query for retrieve minimum and maximum file size uploaded in each document library per month in a site

Tags: 2013, 2010

Hi for the development purpose in development environment
i want to get minimum and maximum file size uploaded in each document library per month  in a site,how can i get this?

there is many folders in side a document library and each folder has 2000 documents  and I want to get max and min uploaded documents per month

Comment: Why you require query on database to get file size of each document?

Comment: There is many  document libraries and more number of  documents in each document library

Comment: I want to get uploaded documents per month

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing server side code, below code will be useful for you:

```
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();
query.Webs = "<Webs Scope=\"Site\">";
query.Lists = "<Lists BaseType=\"1\" />";
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name=\"LinkFilename\" /><FieldRef Name=\"FileSizeDisplay\" />";
DataTable dtLibs = web.GetSiteData(query);
```

Comment: hi how i use this query?

Comment: This is server side code. You have to create webpart or layout page

Comment: It will get all documents from all document libraries of site in datatable .